# barplot- changing position of legend + any way to manually change colour of legend key?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data frame where I've manually coloured the bars to correspond to the column name. However, when I try to add a legend (legend = TRUE doesn't work), the colours are incorrect. In addition, the legend overlaps with the chart itself. How do I adjust the position of the legend, and is there any way to change the colour of the key (the boxes themselves)?

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5),B=c(1,6,3,8,4),C=c(2,1,4,8,9), D=c(4,1,2,4,6))
row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5")
print(df)

   A B C D
R1 3 1 2 4
R2 2 6 1 1
R3 1 3 4 2
R4 4 8 8 4
R5 5 4 9 6

col.colors <- c(A="green", B="red", C="yellow", D="blue")
barplot(as.vector(as.matrix(df)), names = as.matrix(df), 
        col=rep(col.colors[colnames(df)], each=nrow(df)), legend.text=c("A","B","C","D"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want this:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df), beside=T, col=rep(col.colors, each=nrow(df)), space=c(.25, .25),
        names.arg=unlist(df))
legend('topleft', legend=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), pt.bg=col.colors, pch=22, horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

The reason why we need an extra `legend` command here is that this kind of `barplot` is rather unusual.

Usually we do

```
barplot(t(df), beside=TRUE, col=col.colors, legend.text=names(df), 
        args.legend=list(x='topleft', horiz=TRUE))
```

[image]

or

```
barplot(as.matrix(df), beside=TRUE, col=2:6, legend.text=rownames(df),
        args.legend=list(x='topleft', ncol=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code with some modifications:

```
col.colors <- c(A="green", B="red", C="yellow", D="blue")
barplot(as.vector(as.matrix(df)), names = as.matrix(df), 
        col = rep(col.colors, each = nrow(df)))
legend("topleft", inset = c(0.01, 0.01), legend = colnames(df), 
       fill = col.colors, border = col.colors, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]